# Deleting python function reference

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I wrote the following code, it executes fine:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")


def test():
    r = hello
    r()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Then, I tried deleting the `hello` function reference:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")


def test():
    r = hello
    r()
    del hello


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

**But I received the following error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/deepak.ahire/Documents/my_projects/testing_decorators/main.py",
> line 12, in
>
> test()
>
> File
> "/Users/deepak.ahire/Documents/my_projects/testing_decorators/main.py",
> line 6, in test
>
> r = hello
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hello' referenced before assignment

What is the cause for this? As I wrote the `del` statement after `r = hello`.

Comment: Add `global hello` to your function to "fix" the issue. What's happening is that the compiler performs an optimisation to determine where to find the variable, by default it uses the global namespace, if it detects any sort of assignment or apparently a `del` it looks for the variable in locals. You can force/tell the interpreter where to look for the variable by using the keywords `global/nonlocal`

Comment: That's because `hello` needs to be defined/declared within the function `test` first. You can do del r instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Iain Shelvington have already answered your question, but just adding to that,
If you disassemble your code `del` emits `DELETE_FAST` Opcode and by looking at [it's the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/ceval.c#L3054), you can see that it will try to lookup `hello`(`oparg` in this case is `hello`) from **local variables** of function `test`, if it not found, this will result in `unbound_local_error`(`UnboundLocalError` exception in python layer)

```
TARGET(DELETE_FAST) {
    PyObject *v = GETLOCAL(oparg);
    if (v != NULL) {
        SETLOCAL(oparg, NULL);
        DISPATCH();
    }
    goto unbound_local_error;
}
```

Comment: So for assignment, the compiler by default looks for globals, and for del the compiler by default looks for locals. Correct?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire The name lookup in python follows [LEGB Rule](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#using-the-legb-rule-for-python-scope). But for `del` statements it [removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global statement in the same code block](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement)

Comment: Thank you @Abdul Niyas P M and @ Iain Shelvington.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused because you want to delete "hello" before it is assigned and here " hello "
acts like a variable
so, instead of doing that you can write your code like :

```
def hello():
print("Hello")
def test():
    r = hello
    r()
    del r
if __name__ == '__main__':
     test()
```

here , you can't delete the function call but can delete the class function